# How to add vertical scroll bar to a table that has the first column always fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a solution.

I have created a table; its first column will always be fixed whenever the user scrolls horizontally.

But right now I am facing one more issue that if there are too many records the users have to go to the end of the page to scroll horizontally.

Is it possible to make it vertically scroll-able with CSS only?

Here is my code:

```
<style>
   .row {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   margin-right: -15px;
   margin-left: -15px;
   }
   /* width */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 10px;
   height:7px;
   }
   /* Track */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background:#eaeaea;
   }
   /* Handle */
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: #ccc; 
   }
   .tg{
   overflow:hidden;
   word-break:normal;
   display:table;
   }
   .tg .tg-29qf{
   border-color:inherit;
   text-align:left}
   .tg .tg-xldj{
   border-color:inherit;
   text-align:left}
   .tg .sticky-col-1{
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: auto;
   width: 445px;
   }
   .zui-scroller {
   margin-left: 445px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: visible;
   width: 890px;
   }
   .tg .tg-kiyi{
   border-color:inherit;
   text-align:left;
   min-width:150px;
   display:table-cell;
   padding: 7px 0px;
   }
   .tg .cover-head-cell{
   min-width:300px;
   text-align:center;
   }
   .tg .tg-29qf{
   text-align:left;
   min-width:100px;
   }
   .tg .tg-xldj{
   border-color: inherit;
   text-align: left;
   min-width: 150px;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 15px 0px;
   }
   .pad-l-r-15{
   padding: 10px 5px !important;
   }
   .tg .tg-dvid{
   border-color:inherit;
   text-align:left;
   vertical-align:top;
   min-width:150px;
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}}
   .report-row div {
   }
   .total-row div {
   padding: 15px 5px !important;
   background: #fff !important;
   font-size: 14px !important;
   color: #575962 !important;
   font-weight: 500;
   border-bottom:1px solid #ccc !important;
   }
   div.report-row.odd,
   .sticky-col-1.odd {
   background-color: #F5F5F5;
   }
   div.report-row.even,
   .sticky-col-1.even {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   }
   .report-row-header div {
   padding: 15px 5px !important;
   background: #f4f3f8 !important;
   font-size: 14px !important;
   border: none !important;
   color: #575962 !important;
   font-weight: 500;
   }
</style>
<div class="row" style="">
   <div class="tg-wrap">
      <div class="zui-scroller">
         <div class="tg">
            <div class="report-row-header ">
               <div class="tg-kiyi sticky-col-1">#</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">Impressions</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">Conversion</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi ">Bids</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi ">Wins</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">Spend</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">eCPA</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">eCPM</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">Win Rate</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">Clear Rate</div>
               <div class="tg-kiyi">Actions</div>
            </div>
            <div class="total-row ">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1 text-right" style="    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc !important;
                  height: 52px;"></div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">62.36K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">227.69K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">108.45K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 64.11</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 64.11</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 64.11</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 64.11</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 64.11</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">N/A</div>
            </div>
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
               }-->
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">RTB_SA_INR_IOS</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">3.38K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">6.32K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">3.39K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 2.75</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.81</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.87 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.87 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Grindr - Gay chat</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">6.44K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">33.49K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">22.47K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 17.30</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.69</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.49 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">5.20 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">TextNow - Unlimited Text + Calls</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">499.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">26.38K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">25.39K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 11.08</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">22.21</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.04 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">52.86 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">iFunny :)</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">6.15K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">9.41K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">6.49K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 2.34</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.38</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.45 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.53 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Wordscapes</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">10.49K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">16.34K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">10.87K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 5.24</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.50</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.50 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.56 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Whisper - Share, Express, Meet</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">404.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">7.31K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">400.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.25</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.63</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">18.29 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">18.10 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Mr Bullet</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.72K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">5.62K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.81K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 1.22</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.45</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.00 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.07 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Trebel Music - Song Downloader</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">240.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.13K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">233.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.18</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.74</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">4.86 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">4.72 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Musi - Unlimited Music For YouTube</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">11.21K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">16.97K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">15.64K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 7.80</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.70</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.09 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.51 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Happy Color – Color by Number</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">4.36K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">10.65K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">4.40K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 3.96</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.91</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.42 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.44 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Skout - Chat, Meet New People</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">448.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.25K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">482.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.24</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.53</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.59 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.79 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Poke Genie for Pokemon Go Auto IV Calculator</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">201.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">735.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">228.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.10</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.49</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">3.22 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">3.66 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Sudoku - Classic Logic Game</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">646.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.77K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">645.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.41</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.64</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.75 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.74 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">Solitaire·</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">25.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">45.10K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">18.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.01</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.56</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">2.51K %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.80K %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">UNICORN - Number Coloring Book</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">163.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.53K</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">195.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.08</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.47</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">7.87 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">9.41 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="report-row ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
               <div class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                  <span class="ng-tns-c0-0 ng-star-inserted">theCHIVE</span>
               </div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">560.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">931.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">555.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">$ 0.44</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.00</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">0.79</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.68 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">1.66 %</div>
               <div class="tg-xldj pad-l-r-15">
               </div>
            </div>

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the same code: https://jsfiddle.net/vjg0a7o8/

Comment: Could you fix your title please a column is vertical a row is horizontal so you either wants the first column with a horizontal scroll bar or the first row with a vertical scroll bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to make it vertically scroll-able with CSS only?

Short answer: it is, but let's analyze the problem first:

To show this I have made a minimal example of yours (I used a real `table` and not `divs` and chose a layout that differs just a bit, but the problems will still be the same and are applying to your code snippets as well).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sticky-left {
  text-align: left;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.sticky-left td {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

thead th {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  background: #f4f3f8;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  color: #575962;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.content-table {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="sticky-left">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="content-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

A scroll bar is added to an element if the content **overflows** the `flow`.
In other words:

> The `overflow property` specifies whether to clip the content or to add scrollbars when the content of an element is too big to fit in the specified area.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp).

---

#### Problem #1

So the first approach would be to just add a horizontal scroll bar on the y-axis by just making the table smaller. So lets so that:
Add `height: 200px` (or whatever size you want) to the `.wrapper` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/gwz3rce6/ 
(I have to use JSFiddle because the character limit would be exceeded if I would add a code snippets every time)

At first glance it seems very promissing. You have the scroll bar right where you want it.
The problem is: The fixed column on the left side is out of flow since we added `position: absolute` and `left: 0`. The problem is that `position: absolute` uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling as long as it isn't inside a positioned ancestor (e.g. a parent element with `position: relative`).

#### Problem #2

So why don't we just add `position: relative` to the `.wrapper`? The fixed column should then be inside the container and should not orient itself at the document body.
Well, and it does!

https://jsfiddle.net/gwz3rce6/1/

But that leads to the problem! The left column isn't fixed anymore... why is that? Now it gets a bit complicated:

To understand the problem let's imagine that the left column is actually outside of the `.wrapper` element and we positioned it `absolute` like in my first example. You would still have the problem in **Problem #1** but at least you would not have the problem described at the beginning of **Problem #2**. So the left column is actually fixed to left side.

Note that you have two containers here: The table where you have a vertical scroll bar and the document. By scrolling the table it does not have an effect on the left column right now because it is outside of your table and has, therefore, nothing to do with it. And this is what `position: absolute` does. It simulates the element outside of your container if it isn't in a positioned container (e.g. `position: relative`).

Since it orients itself at the document you would have an effect if you add a scrollbar to the `body`.

So lets put the left column inside of your container again. By adding `position: relative` the absolute positioned element can only move inside this container and does **not** orient itself at the document. That is why it is now inside of the container and not outside (like in **Problem #1**) of it. But this is also the reason why it isn't fixed anymore. It is the same reason why adding a scrollbar on the body would have an effect on the left column in **Problem #1**.

Yes, it is kind of hard to understand... but it is also kind of hard to put it in words. I still hope you learned something from it and it answers your question, even though I haven't provided a solution yet.

There are also some different approaches to the task but none of these work (except for the one I will describe now) and I covered the most promising approach.
Also, if I did something wrong and overlooked something feel free to comment.

---

#### Solution

The solution to this problem is to use `position: sticky`.

https://jsfiddle.net/zvgn7u49/

In your case you would add this to the `.tg .sticky-col-1` class instead of `position: absolute`.

> An element with `position: sticky;` is positioned based on the user's scroll position.
>
> A sticky element toggles between `relative` and `fixed`, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like `position:fixed`).

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp).

But, be careful as it lacks browser support for specific elements. Some browsers (like Safari) also require the `-webkit-` prefix. You can get further information [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

**Edit:** While I was making a fiddle for your code I discovered that [@Icaro Heimig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11266897/icaro-heimig) already covered this solution and also did a pen.

> I've made an example on codepen: https://codepen.io/icaromh/pen/gyJdvZ

Comment: Appropriate your time to work on solution! but i already have tried position sticky thing
Issue if i have white color if first column whenever user scrolls it literally looks like text is overlapping whenever user scrolls. that's why i did not go with that solution

Comment: try putting white color instead of lightgrey you will understand what i am saying

Comment: I don't see the issue. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Or maybe I don't understand it. What do you mean with "overlapping"?

Comment: If you mean this: https://imgur.com/a/aA71Vfe then just add `.tg-kiyi.sticky-col-1 { padding: 0 !important; }` to the end of your CSS.

Comment: Nope try in your solution on codependent just change BG color light grey to white

Comment: Only from the left column or every row? And can you somehow provide a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: I am sorry mate ! i guess z-index thing worked. Sometimes i feels like i am idiot missing simple thing here :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element that simulates a scroll bar, and place it where you want. Without using JS, it is unlikely to get the desired result.

Or try using jquery.doubleScroll

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#double-scroll').doubleScroll();
});
```

```css
#double-scroll{
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="double-scroll">
  <table id="very-wide-element">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But i also have to maintain first column fixed functionality!
If i give container fixed height and apply vertical scrollbar, my first column will be fixed and remaining will be be scrolling, that should not happen

Comment: Have you checked fiddle link that i have shared?

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use position sticky on your application?

I've made an example on codepen: https://codepen.io/icaromh/pen/gyJdvZ

If it's possible to use `position: sticky` it's kinda easy to reproduce it on your code :D

Edit: I've removed a lot of `overflows` and applied only for the parent div. Also, I've modified some `z-index` so the headers and first col appear right.

**Can I Use**: https://caniuse.com/css-sticky

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have an x-fixed column and scrollbars in x and y axis at same time only by css.

Scrollbars can be at bottom or at right side of a div, or both - I have tried in all ways:

An outter div scrollbar may hide an inner div scrollbar - not acceptable. That is because the inner scroll must be at the edge of div and can be scrolled away out of border. The only possibility in css to have both scrollbars at the same time is to set it on same div by:

```
overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;
```

..that equals to..

```
overflow: auto;
```

That works fine! 
So now you want a fixed column on that? 
The only way is **position**: *absolute*, *fixed* or *sticky*. 
These are the only ways to detach element from document.
And none of these can detach only the x or y axis to be scrollable in the other axis.

Make it so far as possible with css and have panel(s) fixed to the document by a little piece of javascript. Those with javascript turned off can have an extra vertical scrollbar for the column.

Answer (score -1):

```
.tg-wrap{
         height:100vh; /*covers whole screen*/
         overflow:scroll;
        }
```

Comment: it applies scroll to wrap, though vertical scrollbar will be there but it wont help fixed column cells to adjust with scroll

Comment: Check my jsfiddle you will understand more

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the header/first column onto a seperate .html document, and then the rest onto another. Then creating a third .html file and adding two iframes. It is a basic approach.

Comment: First understand my question !

Answer (score -1):

I think i have a solution for you.

Add this to your CSS.

****CSS*****

```
.tg-wrap{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And remove the width: 890px attribute from .zui-scroller.

Note: I added 50% just for demonstration purposes. You can set your height.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't downvote but you got something wrong. The first column shall always be fixed to the left side.

Comment: yep! i believe the author has already fixed the first column by defining the first element of each table row as an absolute element. And just so that it does not go anywhere I suggested removing the width: 890px from zui-scroller class and adding the tg-wrap class to it and it works perfect. I just cross checked in the fiddle. Not sure if this is not what hes looking for.